# Add slider in plotly figure

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, plot, plotly, slider

I am visualizing the data stored in pandas dataframe via plotly.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# ref: https://plotly.com/python/sliders/

if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = px.data.iris()
    df = df.iloc[0:10, :]
    # print(df)
    petal_width = [1.3, 1.4, 1.4]
    # Create figure
    fig = go.Figure()

    # Add traces, one for each slider step
    data = [
            go.Scatter(
                mode="lines+markers",
                x=df['sepal_width'],
                y=df['sepal_length'],
            ),

            go.Scatter(
            mode="lines+markers",
            x=df['sepal_width'],
            y=df['sepal_length']+2,
            ),

            go.Scatter(
                mode="lines+markers",
                x=df['sepal_width'],
                y=df['sepal_length'] + 3,
            )

        ]

    slider_range = min(petal_width), max(petal_width)
    low, high = slider_range

    # slides = []
    # for i in range(3):
    #     slide = dict(
    #         method="update",
    #         args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
    #               {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)}],  # layout attribute
    #     )
    #     slide["args"][0]["visible"][i] = True  # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    #     slides.append(slide)
    #
    # sliders = [
    #     dict(
    #     active=10,
    #     currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    #     pad={"t": 50},
    #     steps=slides
    # )
    # ]


    fig = go.Figure(data=data)

    #fig.update_layout(
    #    sliders=slider
    #)
    # fig.show()
    with open("check.html", 'a') as f:
        f.write(fig.to_html(full_html=False, include_plotlyjs='cdn'))
```

Plot:

[image]

This figure shows three lines corresponding to the there dataset in `data`. These threee curves are associated with 3 values stored in `petal_width = [1.3, 1.4, 1.4]` .

I would like to add a slider like shown in the example (please see the example plot below) presented [here]
(https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/)

[image]

I'm not really sure how to add the slider. Basically, I want to add the slider and based on the value selected in the slider the corresponding curves in the plot should appear. e.g. if 1.4 is selected in the slider (petal_width), I want the second and third curves to appear.

Suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code is a line chart with no visualization. The graph you want to get is the example on the page in question is a scatter plot with a slider in Dash. What is the goal, do you want a scatterplot with a slider in Plotly?

Comment: @r-beginners Thank you for the reply. Yes, my goal is to add a slider in the first figure posted above.

Comment: Is the purpose of a line chart instead of a scatter plot?

Comment: I'd prefer to use scatter plot

Comment: Also, there is no control in plotly that allows me to arbitrarily decide between ABs. I believe the only ones that are there are continuous sliders or category selection sliders. To illustrate with an example from the official reference, try adding the following code to compare the two charts: `animation_frame='petal_width'` and  `animation_frame='species'`

Comment: Could you please post this as an answer? I'm not sure if I completely understand the details that you shared.

Comment: I have expanded on what I explained in my comment to [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13dkZo0PJ7hAjowQFUcT6ZJkLRUv-E4sl?usp=sharing). Once you have reviewed this content, disable Colab.

Comment: Thank you. If possible, could you please illustrate it for the example code that I have posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
steps = []
for i in range(len(fig.data)):
    step = dict(
        method="update",
        args=[{"visible": [False] * len(fig.data)},
              {"title": "Slider switched to step: " + str(i)}],  # layout attribute
    )
    visible = []
    val = petal_width[i]
    for j in range(len(petal_width)):
        if petal_width[j] == val:
            step["args"][0]["visible"][j] = True # Toggle i'th trace to "visible"
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=1,
    currentvalue={"prefix": "Frequency: "},
    pad={"t": 50},
    steps=steps
)]

fig.update_layout(
    sliders=sliders
)
```

You just need to fix the colors, for all 3 categories.

steps output:

```
[{'method': 'update',
  'args': [{'visible': [True, False, False]},
   {'title': 'Slider switched to step: 0'}]},
 {'method': 'update',
  'args': [{'visible': [False, True, True]},
   {'title': 'Slider switched to step: 1'}]},
 {'method': 'update',
  'args': [{'visible': [False, True, True]},
   {'title': 'Slider switched to step: 2'}]}]
```

Output :
[Step:0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50xqg.png)

[Step:1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUjuh.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please post the complete code?